# Why does my program crash at the end even if it executes all the operations just fine?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have the next code which I want to read an 2D array. It does this, but after the program ends the program crashes every time. I have a bigger program, but here is the only problem. I have also read [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) and I debugged the program.

The question is: why does the program crash at the end even it throughout the expected operation procedure it works fine?

```
void dynamicMemAlloc(int n, int (**arrayPointer)[n][n]){
    *arrayPointer = malloc(sizeof(int[n][n]));
    assert(*arrayPointer != NULL);
}

void readMy2Darray(int n, int array[n][n]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
}
void printMy2Darray(int n, int array[n][n]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(void){
    int n;
    printf("Read the dimension(n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int (*arrayPointer)[n][n];
    dynamicMemAlloc(n, &arrayPointer);
    printf("Read the 2D array:\n");
    readMy2Darray(n, *arrayPointer);
    printf("Printed array:\n");
    printMy2Darray(n, *arrayPointer);
    free(arrayPointer);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: The error here]

Comment: `Why does my program crash even if it works fine?`...what kind of a statement is this?

Comment: you try to free memory that you did not allocate from the heap. you should read up on how memory management works in c.

Comment: I had no idea how to say what I wanted to say

Comment: oh, sorry I misread that.

Comment: How could a program possibly work fine, while it crashes?

Comment: It's quite easy to do - I've done it lots.   Just corrupt the main() return address on the stack.  Result - 'correct' operation and segfault on main() return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
```

goes off by one. C arrays are 0-based indexed. You should have the loop condition set as

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

Otherwise, it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I understand that, but the print function still works fine even if it starts from 1.

Comment: @Timʘɫei read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I used to use the version you suggested until about a week. That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the fourth scanf will write past the end of the malloc()d array and likely overwrite the malloc() bookkeeping, making the free() call run into trouble.

But as specified in the other answer, all of this depends on undefined behaviour and will be implementation-specific.